# How can I add a button to AppBarLayout in android?

Tags: android

I am making an android app , and I want to add 2 button as image below , but I have no idea about how to do it, I have searched a lot but nothing makes sense to me , I am a beginner here, thank you for your help
[image contain app bar layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPCSo.png)

**And this is my code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orang"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            android:textColor="@color/whit" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orang"

        app:tabTextColor="@color/whit"

        />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the button on the right side use options. Create an options menu xml and add items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
         android:id="@+id/action_search"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
         android:title="@string/search"
         app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Inflate it in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}
```

Handle the click on it (modify to your need):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // do something
            break;                        
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For the menu button on the left side use navigation (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

To flexible, you can add the view to XML:
[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>



    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"

        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , i did it before but i think it is not the correct way to do so , thank you again